# Calculation of e^x without using Math Library

Tags: java

I know that answers to calculation of e^x without using math library are already available.

But I have a small doubt that:

I defined two individual functions:  One is power function to evaluate a^b and another factorial function to evaluate n!. I declared these functions to be static so object not required to be created.

Logic Used:

```
    int l=1; // Declared a variable l and initialised it

    int sum=1;    // The sum variable would be value of e^x

   for(l=1; ; l++)

   {
     sum= sum+ (power(x,l))/(factorial(l)) ; /* Here x is taken as user input and functions are 
                                                 called*/
    }

    System.out.println("The value of e^ "+x +" is " +sum);

  For infinite loop as shown in above code it says unreachable code.
  If i put a condition on l like l<34 then code runs but for l<35 it prints that the value of e^x is infinity.

      So how to get rid of this problem???
```

Comment: Can you show `power` and `factorial` as well?

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple things going wrong here. First of all calculating the exact value of e is impossible because it is an infinite loop. Secondly all of your variables, probably even those in the functions factorial and power are declared as int, and for sure e is not an int and the calculation does not return an int. Thirdly I don't get the intention of the power function. Fourthly, try separating your problems in smaller ones, an solve them in separate functions. As for calculating the Euler's Constant here is an approach:

```
public static double calculateE(int noOfCalculations){
    
    double e = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<noOfCalculations;i++) 
        e += (double)1/factorial(i); 
    return e;   
    
}

public static int factorial(int i) {
    if(i==0)
        return 1;
    return i*factorial(i-1);
}
```

Comment: Thats nice. But how to get rid of infinite loop problem?? And if it is ask to present code for this question can i present above code with changes you mentioned??

Comment: In order two get rid of infinite loop you have to to determine how much accurate you want to be. This is a math problem too. For example you can say ; e = 2.71 or e = 2.71828182845904523. And in order to determine the accuracy degree, we have put a method variable called noOfCalculations in order to decide how much precise we want to be. As for the presentation, it depends for who and what are you presenting it for, but I can sure you that there is no computer scientist or mathematician in the world that says that solution is  wrong nor a good approach.